# split row value by separator and create new columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I I have a Pyspark dataset with a column “channels” that looks like this:

```
channels

name1,name2,name3,name4
happy1,happy2
entity1,entity2,entity3,entity4,entity5
```

I want to create 5 new columns i.e “channel1, channel2, channel3, channel4, channel5”.

Then, I want to split the contents of the “channels” column using the comma separator. After splitting values from each row, I want to put each separated value in a different column.

For example for the first row, the columns should look like this:

```
channel1   channel2  channel3   channel4   channel5
name1       name2      name3      name4        ~
```

When an element is not found, i want to use ~ as the column value. For example in the first row, there were only 4 values instead of 5 so for the channel5 column, I used ~

I only want to use ~, not None or NULL.

How can I achieve this result in pyspark?

I tried this:

```
    df = df.withColumn("channels_split", split(df["channels"], ","))
    df = df.withColumn("channel1", coalesce(df["channels_split"][0], "~"))
    df = df.withColumn("channel2", coalesce(df["channels_split"][1], "~"))
    df = df.withColumn("channel3", coalesce(df["channels_split"][2], "~"))
    df = df.withColumn("channel4", coalesce(df["channels_split"][3], "~"))
    df = df.withColumn("channel5", coalesce(df["channels_split"][4], "~"))
    df = df.drop("channels_split")
```

but it gives me an error that:

```
`~` is missing

You're referencing the column `~`, but it is missing from the schema. Please check your code.
```

Note that I am using pyspark within Foundry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coalesce expects cols as arguments and you are providing String, i think that you should use lit("~")

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a spark problem than a Foundry problem though.

What @M_S said is correct, as the error message was stating, you need a column and should use the lit function.

But be careful if
`spark.sql.ansi.enabled` is set to `True`
then this code will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there are less than 5 items in your array.

Another way to do this would be to ensure that your array has at least 5 elements on each row by adding some ~, then get the first 5 items or by adding a temporary column with the length of the array and use a when condition.

By the way, you don't need to repeat `df =` every time

```py
df = (
    df
    .withColumn("channels_split", split(df["channels"], ","))
    .withColumn("default_values", array_repeat(lit("~"), 5)))
    .withColumn("channels_split", concat(col("channels_split"), col("default_values")))
    .withColumn("channel1", df["channels_split"][0])
    .withColumn("channel2", df["channels_split"][1])
    .withColumn("channel3", df["channels_split"][2])
    .withColumn("channel4", df["channels_split"][3])
    .withColumn("channel5", df["channels_split"][4])
    .drop("channels_split")
)
```